# Adding data to Highcharts after initial rendering

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and initializing the data using;

```
var graph = Highcharts.chart('container', {
................
    series: [{
        color: 'red',
        data: [[5, 2],  [800, 2], [801, 1],[802, 3],[803, 2],[804, 2],[1200, 3]]
    },
.............
}
```

The problem I have is when I want to add more data dynamically, after rendering the initial chart.

In this case I'm using the update;

```
graph.update(
{
    series: [{
        color: 'blue',
        data: [[100, 2],  [101, 2], [102, 1] ]
    },
});
```

And this works but it replaces the entire data set.
So, how should I use the update() function to add points and not replace them?

I saw people are using other functions such as addPoint() and setData() but I couldn't make them work properly...
Thanks in advance
Gus

Comment: check this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-click-to-add. Add example where you are facing difficulty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/opr4Lgpe/

I add all the points in a loop. `redraw` argument (second one) of the `addPoint` function is set to `false` - there's no need to redraw the chart after each addition. The redraw is performed only once in the end.

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  series: [{
    data: [1, 2]
  }]
});

var pointsToAdd = [4, 5, 6, 6, 7];

pointsToAdd.forEach(function(p) {
    chart.series[0].addPoint(p, false);
});

chart.redraw();
```

---

**API reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint